# Getting next and previous document of a specific document

Tags: php, mongodb, database

In mongoDB what is best practice to get the next and previous document of a document using just its `_id`?

Comment: Are you asking something like, `What is the next document in a collection given this ID number?` If so I don't believe Mongo does that. You'd have to do a query, find the ID and then get the next or previous one. If your ID is numeric, then finding the next one you could query for greater than the ID and `limit` the result to 1. Similarly, for the previous one query for items less than the ID and `limit` the result to 1.

Comment: Mongo ObjectId's can be compared.

Answer (score 0):

You can sort by document _id if you'd like to sequence the documents in order of creation.

i.e.

```
db.mycollection.find().sort({_id:-1});
```

See:
http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Optimizing+Object+IDs#OptimizingObjectIDs-Sortbyidtosortbyinsertiontime